How to use SCSS mixins in angular component.scss file?
How do you use a scss mixin in an Angular component?
CONTEXT
I created a file for my scss mixins in /src/styles/_mixins.css and imported this mixins file into the global style file styles.scss like this
// styles.scss    
@use "variables";
@use "mixins";

Then in the year-events.component.scss file of my angular component I tried to use my mixins like this
// year-events.component.scss
@use "mixins";
.events-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;

  @include mixins.screen-size('large') {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)
  }
}

it doesn't work and I get this error
Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "mixins";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/app/calendar/components/year-events/year-events.component.scss 1:1  root stylesheet

And so, after several searches, it says to manually import the mixins file into my component's .ts file, which I did.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-year-events',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    EventCardComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './year-events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./year-events.component.scss', '/src/styles/_mixins.scss'], // added this
})
export class YearEventsComponent implements OnInit {}

but always the same error. What's the reason for this? Shouldn't importing something into the global style file styles.scss benefit all components?
voici mon fichier _mixins.scss
//_mixins.scss    
@mixin screen-size($breakpoint) {
      @if $breakpoint == 'small' {
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
          @content
        }
      } @else if $breakpoint == 'medium' {
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
          @content
        }
      } @else if $breakpoint == 'large' {
        @media (min-width: 1024px) {
          @content
        }
      }
    }

Just to clarify, when I use the mixin in the styles.scss file, it works as follows

You need to specify the relative path to the _mixins.scss file.
@use "../../../../styles/mixins";

Alternatively you can use the includePaths property of the stylePreprocessorOptions in angular.json:
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["src/styles"]
}

This allows you to use your existing component code:
@use "mixins";


Thank you @JSON Derulo ... By the way, nice username :)
